# Using getElementsByTagName to modify a form

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, getelementsbytagname, for-in-loop

I'm new to Javascript, and I've hit a wall on a project.

I have a form I would like to only display the first select element ($initial) in each fieldset until the user has selected an option in $initial. Afterwards, the other selects should show up. And if the user selected the first option in $initial, the other selects would hide themselves again.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var setOpen = function(id) {
    $(id).setAttribute("class", "open");
};
var setClosed = function(id) {
    $(id).removeAttribute("class");
};

var sets = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset");

for(var i = 0; i < sets.length - 1; i++) { //fieldset at the end with no selects is skipped
    var setNode = sets[i].getAttribute("id");
    var selects = $(setNode).getElementsByTagName("select");
    var initial = selects[0].id;
    for (var x = 0; x < selects.length; x++) {
        var selectNode = selects[x].getAttribute("id");
        $(initial).onchange = function() {
            if ($(initial).value != "none") {
                setOpen(selectNode);
            } else {
                setClosed(selectNode);
                setOpen(initial);
            }
        };  
    }
}
```

I was originally using for-in loops but they were giving me wonky results (things like "Object 2 has no method 'getAttribute'"). For some reason using for loops isn't giving me the same errors (this language is fun).

I've been scratching my head over this one for a couple days. I'm sure there's a fairly simple way to get this done, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you had a look at knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/)? It was designed to aid in UI composition, much the same as you are trying to achive.

Comment: @jaq316 Thank you for the link. I hadn't heard of it, though it does look like it could be useful going forward.

Comment: Fun update: I was missing a semi-colon (thanks, JSHint), and now it will display other selects onchange. But it's only displaying the first and last selects. Here it is on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDd9Y). I just realized a huge issue though: even if this were to work, it'd all selects even though that's not what I want. Oh well, guess I'll have to do this more specifically.